# Producer interface in camel

Tags: apache-camel

The apache camel API doc for the Producer interface says "Producer interface provides a channel on which clients can create and invoke message exchanges on an Endpoint". (https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Producer.html)

If we take the Producer implementation of a camel weather component , it has a process method in weather information is requested. But I do not see where a "channel" as per EIP is provided (http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageChannel.html) . Does "channel" in this sentence does not refer to to channel in EIP?

Answer (score 0):

The EIP patterns and the EIP book are covering some patterns that are on a conceptual/abstract level. And the EIP book takes offset in a messaging world, where these patterns are doing messaging exchanges with messaging, and then the channel represents message queues/topics etc.